# Audio processing library for C++

Tags: audio, signal-processing, frequency-analysis

I'm new to signal processing .I want to analyze audio files in sports videos (Fourier transform,analyze frequencies and amplitudes etc.).I'm looking for Audio processing library for C++ like openCV for image processing.Can you please help me to chose good library for this by your experience.Thank you

Answer (score -1):

I found very **full** audio processing class hierarchy in the sources of [Chaotic-DAW](https://github.com/dliganov/Chaotic-DAW/tree/master/rosic).
(**DAW** is Digital Audio Workstation)
(С++, crossplatform)